# Angular: How to make input field with two-way binding show "invalid date" when user provides incorrect date in datepicker

Tags: angular

I have an input field with an angular datepicker that is two-way binded to my model that is of type string. If a user provides an existing date I convert the date with `toISOString()` and the datepicker formats it into `DD/MM/YYYY` in the input field. When a user provides a date that does not exist I set the binded model to `"invalid date"`, but because this string can't be formatted into a date it won't show in my input field. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: You can use the label below the input field to show the error. Inside the Input field, you can't do this because that is only used for date

Comment: You should check https://angular.io/guide/form-validation and show a validation message if the date is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. When the date is changed on the date picker an event is fired. You can check the input and set a different boolean variable to false.
 Then by checking this flag you could either create a tooltip to express the mistake, a modal, an extra div or other element that shows the error, or you could even write on top of the date picker for it to show invalid date on its input.
I would advise in not overriding the date picker input to show the mistake and instead use a fallback date when there is wrong input or don't save the wrong input at all, and communicate to the user via a tooltip or other error showing mechanic what went wrong.
So to sum it up, get the event fired on date change and handle the error there in your preferred way.

P.s. if you want the exact code you can upload yours and I can fix it for you. Ask me if you want any clarification.

Hope it helps